# While downloading xls file from django download code, file is not opening, It shows corrupted

Tags: python, django, xls

Here is my code for xls download using python(Django)

views.py

```
def downloadfile(request, filename=''):
  if filename != '':
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    filename = 'SampleExcel.xls'
    filepath = BASE_DIR + "\SampleExcel\SampleExcel.xls"
    path = open(filepath, encoding='cp437')
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
    response = HttpResponse(path, content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    return response
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect("adduser", {})
```

With this code I am able to download file properly, but while opening that file it shows me error. I attach screenshot of error.

[image]

I have tried this code for solution,

```
if filename != '':
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
  filename = 'SampleExcel.xls'
  filepath = BASE_DIR + "\SampleExcel\SampleExcel.xls" 
  return FileResponse(open(filepath, 'rb') , True, filename)
else:
  return HttpResponseRedirect("adduser", {})
```

This also not works, It shows error 'TypeError at /downloadfile/SampleExcel.xls
HTTP status code must be an integer.', and it is not even downloading.

Please help me. I am stuck here from last 3 days.

`Note: I need to download xls file only, as after downloading it I have to perform import functionality with that downloaded xls file. I can not change xls to xlsx.`

Error Log

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\PCSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run self.finish_response() File "C:\Users\PCSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 184, in finish_response self.write(data) File "C:\Users\PCSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write assert type(data) is bytes, \ AssertionError: write() argument must be a bytes instance [27/Jun/2022 15:07:10] "GET /downloadfile/SampleExcel.xls HTTP/1.1" 500 59`

Answer (score 2):

The `FileResponse` one will work, the issue is that you are not setting the proper keyword arguments.

```
path = open(filepath, 'rb')
response = FileResponse(path, as_attachment=True, filename=filename)
```

Make sure you have added the `'rb'` to the `open` and this should work for you.

Comment: This gives me error ' A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.'

Comment: Can you share the log of the django runserver command.

The `HTTP status code must be an integer.` error happens because you had the True as the second parameter, which is not the same as the as_attachement key work argument. So there must be another issue for the server to return 500.

Comment: I am attaching log in my Question section.

Comment: Can you make sure you have added the `'rb'` to the `open('Sample.xls', 'rb')`?

Comment: Can you please update this in your answer so I can close this Question.